# Smooth movement in pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

So after using Tkinter for our game, we decided to move over to Pyglet. But one of the problems I am having is the movement, in Tkinter I was able to make a smooth movement system but in pyglet all I can do is get the character to move in a jittery way.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key, Window
from pyglet import clock
from threading import Timer

X = 5 #Speed of the player
w = 0 #Controls +y movement
a = 0 #Controls -x movement
s = 0 #Controls -y movement
d = 0 #Controls +x movement

window = Window(width = 500, height = 500) #Defines window

MainChar = pyglet.image.load("Mainchar.png") #Loads the Mainchar.png
Player = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(MainChar, x = 0, y = 0) #Makes MainChar into a sprite

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers): #Looks for a keypress
    print("keypress")
    if symbol == key.W:
        global w
        global a
        global s
        global d
        w = True
    elif symbol == key.A:
        a = True
    elif symbol == key.S:
        s = True
    elif symbol == key.D:
        d = True

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    print("keyup")
    if symbol == key.W:
        w = False
    elif symbol == key.A:
        a = False
    elif symbol == key.S:
        s = False
    elif symbol == key.D:
        d = False
@window.event
def moveT():
    print("cycle")
    def moveD():
        if w == True:
            Player.y += 0.1
        elif a == True:
            Player.x -= 5
        elif s == True:
            Player.y -= 5
        elif d == True:
            Player.x += 5
        moveT()
    moveTimer = Timer(0.01, moveD)
    moveTimer.start()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    Player.draw()

moveT()
pyglet.app.run()
```

The reason I have w, a, s and d as bools, this is so I can move the character with the key held instead of a keypress.

Any help would be wonderful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you use pythons [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). This doesn't trigger the pyglet window to be redrawn.
You've to use [`pyglet.clock`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/clock.html) and to schedule a function to be called every time the clock is ticked. This causes that the pyglet window is updated, too and the `on_draw()` event is triggered. e.g.:

```py
@window.event
def moveT(dt):

    if w == True:
        Player.y += 0.1
    elif s == True:
        Player.y -= 5

    if a == True:
        Player.x -= 5
    elif d == True:
        Player.x += 5

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(moveT, 1 / 60)
```

Further more `w`, `a`, `s` and `d` have to be declared [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) in `on_key_release`, too.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key, Window
from pyglet import clock

X = 5 #Speed of the player
w, a, s, d = False, False, False, False 

window = Window(width = 500, height = 500) #Defines window

MainChar = pyglet.image.load("Mainchar.png")
Player = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(MainChar, x = 0, y = 0)

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers): #Looks for a keypress
    global w, a, s, d
    if symbol == key.W:
        w = True
    elif symbol == key.A:
        a = True
    elif symbol == key.S:
        s = True
    elif symbol == key.D:
        d = True

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    global w, a, s, d
    if symbol == key.W:
        w = False
    elif symbol == key.A:
        a = False
    elif symbol == key.S:
        s = False
    elif symbol == key.D:
        d = False

@window.event
def moveT(dt):

    if w == True:
        Player.y += 0.1
    elif s == True:
        Player.y -= 5

    if a == True:
        Player.x -= 5
    elif d == True:
        Player.x += 5

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    Player.draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(moveT, 1 / 60)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, but do you know of a way to make diagonal movement possible? Since I am coding an arcade game I would be happy to leave it out, but future projects might require it.

Comment: @ChippyT I've change the event callback `moveT`, see the answer. That does  the job.

Comment: Ah sorry, I tend to copy things longhand so I can remember them better.